# Como agrego un subdominio a mi lista de permitidos Cors en mi api Node JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, cpanel

> Tengo una web alojada en un host con el administrador cpanel, esta
> web cuenta con un dominio principal y un subdominio que uso para
> acceso administrador las cuales funcionan haciendo consultas a la
> misma api creada en Node JS.
>
> Ya configuré previamente un dominio en permitidos para hacer consultas
> en la api con Cors de Node JS, ahora intenté agregar el subdominio
> pero al realizar las consultas me da error de:
>
> Access to fetch at 'https://dominio-principal/api/' from origin
> 'https://sub.dominio' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>
> Esto es muy extraño ya que configure de esta manera ambos dominios:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['https://dominio-principal', 'https://sub.dominio'],
    methods: ['GET','POST','DELETE','UPDATE','PUT','PATCH']
}));
```

> y el dominio-principal si puede realizar consultas sin problemas pero
> el sub.dominio me da ese error.
>
> alguien que tenga una respuesta ya que busque en google y no logre
> mucho. De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisa bien que estás usando https y no http, ya que el protocolo CORS considera dos dominios diferentes `http://ab` y `https://ab`

Comment: @PabloLozano si amigo esta configurado tal cual los dos como https y el subdominio tiene redireccion automatica a https asi que fijo que las consultas las hago desde https tambien.